# MySQL get all rows based on a specific column value (filter by column)

Tags: mysql

I have this table A here:

```
| colA | colB
| 1    | 2
| 2    | 2 
| 3    | 3
| 3    | 2
```

I want to query all rows where `colB` is both 3 and 2. In which the result would be:

```
|colA  | colB
| 3    | 3
| 3    | 2
```

I tried querying:

```
select * from A where colB = 2 AND colB= 3
```

But I keep getting an empty response. Tried `OR` but it also won't work. I understand that what I experimented is sort of a "row" filtering.

Is there a way to handle "column" filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from A
where colA IN (select colA 
               from A 
               where colB IN (2, 3)
               group by colA
               having count(distinct colB) = 2)
```

or with a `JOIN`:

```
select A.*
from A 
join (select colA 
      from A 
      where colB IN (2, 3)
      group by colA
      having count(distinct colB) = 2
) as t on A.colA = t.ColA
```

Comment: I've updated my question. hehe Due to the mix up I would like to clarify, does this address my updated question? thanks!

Comment: Quick question, why count = 2?

Comment: @Jhn Because `colB` can be either 2 or 3. Using `count(distinct colB) = 2` predicate we make sure that `colB` takes **both** values.

Comment: Does this value support if I would have a different column filter for `colB` let's say, either 4 or 5?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if the values are 4,5 or 2, 3 or whatever as long as you check against ***2*** separate values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107601/discussion-between-jhn-and-giorgos-betsos).

Comment: What if I have more than 2 filters.. Should I set the count to the number of filters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 from YourTable s
             WHERE a.colA = s.colA
              and s.colB in(2,3)
             GROUP BY s.colA having count(distinct s.colB) = 2)
```